# Number too large

Tags: java

I got result as  integer number too large  when following program compiled,

```
import java.io.*;
class test
{
    int i =09;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {  
        test s=new test();
        s.test();
    }
    void test()
    {
        System.out.println("Number is " +i);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because of prefix `0`. You'll have to change it to something like: `int i = 9;`

Answer (score 1):

Numbers starting with 0 are considered octal notation. So only 0-7 digits are valid.